# Integral Issues.

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle \int \cosh ^2t\,\sinh ^5t \; \textrm{d}t \,$

Can't for the life of me figure this one out. I have tried various substitutions. The pythagorean hyperbolic identity, the double variable identity. Nothing. Could someone give me a push please.

Comment: Take the $\sinh^5=(\sinh^2)^2\sinh=(\cosh^2-1)^2\sinh$  Then change variable $y=\cosh$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some manipulation using $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1\implies \sinh^4t=(\cosh^2t-1)^2$:
$$\cosh ^2t\,\sinh ^5t =\sinh t \cosh^6 t-2 \sinh t \cosh^4 t+\sinh t \cosh^2 t$$
Now try $x=\cosh t,{\rm d}x/{\rm d}t=\sinh t$

Comment: Done and done!, thanks ever so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Using $u=e^t$, you have 
$$\frac1{2^7}\int(u+u^{-1})^2(u-u^{-1})^5\frac{du}u=\frac1{2^7}\int\left(
u^6
-3u^4
+u^2
+5
-\frac5{u^2}
-\frac1{u^4}
+\frac3{u^6}
-\frac1{u^8}
\right)du.$$
Hence,
$$\frac1{2^7}\left(
\frac{u^7}7
-\frac{3u^5}5
+\frac{u^3}3
+5u
+\frac5{u}
+\frac1{3u^3}
-\frac3{5u^5}
+\frac1{7u^7}
\right)+C,$$
$$\frac1{2^6}\left(
\frac{\cosh 7t}7
-\frac{3\cosh5t}5
+\frac{\cosh3t}3
+5\cosh t
\right)+C,$$